# js how to avoid mouse events clashes on different elements

Tags: javascript, html, events

As a javascript learning exercise, i have made a little app which (should) let me create a web page 'graphically'(dreamweaver style). I've added as separate scripts a basic custom menu and a message popup. The menu opens on left mouse clicks binded to document.body, so anywhere on the page including the popup (if present, of course). Is there a way to avoid such behavior?

Edit

Here is the (rough) code for the function handling the drag operations on the popup:

```
window.addEventListener('click', show_mnu, false); // Menu onclick event (simply shows the menu onscreen)

mb_hdr.addEventListener('mousedown', drag, false); // Popup event handlers
document.addEventListener('mouseup', drag, false); //


var dragOffsetX, dragOffsetY;
function drag(evt)
{
    var evt = evt||window.event;
    var target = document.getElementById('popup');

    switch(evt.type)
    {
        case 'mousedown':
        {
            dragOffsetX = evt.clientX - target.offsetLeft;
            dragOffsetY = evt.clientY - target.offsetTop;
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
            break;
        }
        case 'mouseup':
        {
            dragOffsetX = dragOffsetY = null;
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
            break;
        }
        case 'mousemove' :
        {
            if(dragOffsetX && dragOffsetY)
            {
                target.style.left = (evt.clientX - dragOffsetX) + 'px';
                target.style.top  = (evt.clientY - dragOffsetY) + 'px';
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    evt.stopPropagation(); //????
}
```

Comment: In the event handler, check the target element and execute based on if it is the menu or not.

Comment: probably a much better way but you could clear the binding using onmouseover the popup and reset it onmouseout

Comment: If the popup has its own click handler, it needs to prevent event bubbling. If not, your document click handler has to check whether the target is in the popup and return without displaying the menu. It's hard to be more detailed without seeing your code.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your useful (and quick) answers. Bic, i got a similar idea from another post, but it seems not a so 'generic' approach to me (separate scripts, to use together or not as needed) and i'm not ready for a UI library thing. jing3142, if i'm correct, the same applies to your solution, as the popup script needs to have knowledge of the menu script to reset it's click event on mouseover. Barman suggestion seems the more appropriate way to handle my problem, but, so far, i don't really figured out how event bubbling prevention works (shame on me).

Comment: Maybe I am simply stupid, but I can't make heads or tails of what you are tring to do. Could you please explain in more details. However, QuircksMode explains event bubbling in great details, you should check it out. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: If I understand correctly you are asking how to do stop event propagation, the quirckmore link explains that as well.

Comment: Yes, Illimar. The stupid one here it's me. I forgot to insert the events call into the code. As you can see, clicking anywhere on the page fires the click event showing the menu, including when clicking on the popup (so pressing a button, or dragging/resizing the popup can make the menu appear above it, which is what i'm trying to avoid). I hope i make myself clear. Sorry and thank you for the help. I'll check the link you give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you already read about event bubbling and propagation in the links in the comments to your question: if you click on any element, the event propagates down until it reaches window, with its `show_mnu` handler.

To cancel the propagation, you need to add this handler

```
function stop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    (e||event).cancelBubble = true; // if you need to support IE<9
}
```

to every mousedown, mouseup and click handler you do not wish to propagate it down.

See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aXzP8/): clicking the gray box stops the propagation to window.

**Note** if you want to implement drag&drop, you may find [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp) useful, since it uses HTML5 features which are [supported well on desktop systems](http://caniuse.com/#search=drag).